# Visual Studio don't run IOS simulator after update Version 16.5.4

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Is there anyone face IOS simulator issue when run it on xamarin forms project after update visual studio to Version 16.5.4 ???
coz i can't run the simulator after this update
inform that i use windows 10 pro 64bit and use remote apple osx catalina updated to latest version

Comment: Login to the Mac, run XCode, be sure to install any updates if prompted and accept any license agreements

Comment: did all this steps before i post this question

Comment: What do you mean by don't run here? You can't see the simulator options or the simulator does not show after you run your project?